# why is it that mstl decomposition models the higher frequency first?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, multiple-seasonalities

I'm looking at the code for [mstl decomposition](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/mstl.R) and also at this [mstl explanation](http://www.gardner.fyi/blog/STL-Part-I/) and I see that the higher frequency seasonality (e.g. hour-of-day) is modeled first, the series is de-seasonalized and then the lower frequency (e.g. hour-of-week) is modeled.

Why is that? isn't it difficult for the hour-of-day seasonality to ignore the low weekends? why can't it be the other way around - model the hour-of-week seasonality (ignoring the daily noise by setting a low `s.window`), and then de-seasonalize thus making all days the same, and then model the hour-of-day seasonality?